# On the sphere, what is the shortest smooth curve passing through three points?

Tags: geometry

On the sphere, what is the shortest smooth curve passing through three points?  I think it is an arc, but I do n’t know how to prove it to be an arc.
It is not necessarily a geodesic, because these three points are not necessarily on a great circle.

Comment: Is the circle a geodesic?

Comment: First of all, you would only need an arc of that circle to pass through all three points, unless you mean a smooth _closed_ curve. Anyway, it seems unlikely that this would be true for three points not already on the same great circle. I would expect there to be smooth transformations that would "straighten out" some parts of the curve while making it turn more sharply as needed at one of the points, while keeping the curve smooth.

Comment: I think if I were trying to show that I would use calculus of variations.  But your unknowns are the two intermediate curve segments, with a boundary condition that includes matching derivatives at the shared endpoint.

Comment: If you can prove the corresponding point in the euclidean plane, then you cab prove it in your space too.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch It is not necessarily a geodesic, because these three points are not necessarily on a great circle.

Comment: @DavidK You mean to pass three points in an arc, then we will get the shortest curve?

Comment: @Allawonder Any three points on the sphere are on a plane.  Do you think the arc is the shortest?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Do you also think this is an arc with the same radius?

Comment: @z.qmpx My point was: *In a euclidean plane, what is the shortest smooth curve passing through three points?* If you can answer this, then you can answer your question as well.

Comment: The arc is shorter than the complete circle. But it is not the shortest smooth curve through the three points. The arc is not what you asked for, and what you asked for does not exist. You will never find a proof of what you think, because what you are thinking is false.

Comment: @Allawonder My question is on the sphere.  The sphere is not flat.

Comment: @DavidK Are you saying that there is no shortest smooth curve through three points?

Comment: @z.qmpx Oh, I didn't know that. Obviously I can't read. SMH.

Comment: There is no shortest smooth curve. There is a shortest curve, but it is not smooth, and there are many smooth curves that are close to the same length. Every number greater than that length is the length of some smooth curve through the three points.

Comment: @DavidK No shortest?

Comment: It's like the smallest positive number. There isn't one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess, often the shortest *piecewise* smooth curve would be a V-shaped curve that goes directly from one of the points to another one, then bends sharply there and goes directly to the last point. May have to permutate the three points to find the shortest "V".

Once you have the shortest *piecewise* smooth curve, let us say with length $L$, then for any tiny positive $\epsilon$, you can smooth the bend at the middle point to get a smooth curve with length $L + \epsilon$. None of these is "the shortest" one. So the shortest may not exist.

---

And if you mean the shortest *closed* curve, again you start with *piecewise* smooth curves, and get a spherical triangle (each edge shall have a length of at most half the circumference of the sphere). If the perimeter of the triangle is $L$, then smooth curves exist for all lengths $L + \epsilon$ (but not for length $L$).

Then only case where you can find a shortest smooth curve, is if the three points are on the same great circle.

Comment: Do you also think this is an arc with the same radius?

Comment: @z.qmpx I think it is clear from the text of the answer that the response to your comment would be "no".

Comment: By "directly" you mean with geodesic curvature equal to $0$ ? Then this idea is very similar to what I would have expected 

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch The three points do not necessarily determine the geodesic line.

Comment: Your answer should have a picture.

Comment: @z.qmpx You can see an image at [commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Spherical-triangle.png](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Spherical-triangle.png). The three points are labeled $A$, $B$, and $C$. The red curve (piecewise smooth) is the shortest _closed_ curve passing through $A$, $B$, and $C$. There are smooth curves that look the same except if you zoom in a lot at the corners you will see that they are "rounded" to make the curve smooth in a neighborhood of them. To see the shorted curve that is not closed, remove the longest side in the red triangle.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3617412/693433

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen  What do you think of this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3617412/693433