# What is the shortest line connecting these two points and not intersecting the concentric circles?

Tags: geometry

There are a pair of concentric circles on the plane. There are two points E and D in the circle.

- What is the shortest line connecting these two points and not intersecting the concentric circles?
- If points D and E are infinitely close to the inner circle, what is the shortest path connecting the two points?

[image]

Comment: Draw the two external tangents from E to the inner circle; draw the two external tangents from D to the inner circle. This produces two paths from D to E: follow a tangent from D to the inner circle, traverse along the inner circle for a bit, and then traverse a tangent from the inner circle to E. Choose the shorter of these two paths.

Comment: What kind of line do you allow?  Clearly not a straight one.  Does it have to be straight segments, or is a curve allowed?  Think of tightening a string between the points.

Comment: Can it be a curve in a plane intersecting your plane s.t. the intersection line passes through the center of the concentric circle?

Comment: @angryavian If it cannot be a straight line, must it be a smooth curve?

Comment: @RossMillikan Must be smooth curves.

Comment: @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya It is not allowed to intersect with concentric circles.

Comment: @z.qmpx:  the curve angryavian suggested has continuous first derivative.  Is that smooth enough?  It can be made infinitely differentiable with changes you can't see, but not easy to describe.

Comment: Ross Millikan is right; you must make precise what you mean by smooth.

Comment: @RossMillikan Smooth means derivable curves.

Comment: That is one definition.  In that case the first suggestion works.  In other contexts it means infinitely differentiable.  @angryavian:  please answer using your suggestion.

Comment: @RossMillikan If points D and E are infinitely close to the inner circle, what is the shortest path connecting the two points?

Comment: There is no such thing as infinitely close unless you mean they are on the inner circle.  In that case the path has to touch the inner circle.  If you don't allow the path to touch the inner circle there is no shortest path.  Given any path, there is another closer to the circle that is shorter.

Comment: @RossMillikan If two points are on the inner circle, then the shortest path from one point to another is the path on the inner circle?

Comment: Yes, it is.....

Answer (score 3):

(Copying my earlier comment): Draw the two external tangents from E to the inner circle; draw the two external tangents from D to the inner circle. This produces two paths from D to E: follow a tangent from D to the inner circle, traverse along the inner circle for a bit, and then traverse a tangent from the inner circle to E. Choose the shorter of these two paths.

Comment: If points D and E are infinitely close to the inner circle, what is the shortest path connecting the two points?

Comment: @z.qmpx It will be close to simply walking along the inner circle

Comment: What do you think about @RossMillikan's answer?

Comment: @z.qmpx I agree with everything he says. My answer is purposely vague ("close to ...") because your terminology is also vague ("infinitely close to the inner circle").

Comment: I feel you are rigorous. If two points are on the inner circle, then the shortest path from one point to another is the path on the inner circle?